# Phalcon : How to access global function?

Tags: php, function, class, phalcon

I am totally new to use phalcon. 
1. I have created a directory by name library
2. In that directory i have created a file by name commonfunctions.php 
3. and i written a

```
abstract class Commonfunctions extends Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component
{
    Public function ProfileImage() //function to set profile pic
    {
       $auth = $this->session->get('auth');
       $user_id = $auth['id'];     //get session id
       $TblPersonaldetails = TblPersonaldetails::findFirst("user_id = ".$user_id);
       echo "pic = ".$profile_pic = $TblPersonaldetails->profile_pic;  //get profil_pic path from db
    }
}
```

but I am getting notice message from "Notice: Access to undefined property TblPersonaldetails::profile_pic in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\app\library\Commonfunctions.php on line 98"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that `$TblPersonaldetails` has property `profile_pic` ?

Comment: You can do a var_dump($TblPersonaldetails->toArray()) and view all properties. If you have set a custom columnMap (e.g. profile_pic => profilePic) use $TblPersonaldetails->profilePic instead.

Comment: yes TblPersonaldetails has property profile_pic

Comment: Thanks sectus and dompie for your instant reply i got the solution, by using $profilePic = $TblPersonaldetails->getProfilePic(); this code my issue get resolved

Comment: in future i suggest always add all your fields in model as private vars and config set/geters for setting/getting your values. This way you will always be ready to add data validation, make changes easily and never face such bugs as now. you should always always use setters & getters

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for.

Service create a folder called **Service**, Then move your **Commonfunctions** into the neewly created **Service** folder. Inside your **Commonfunctions** file added the **namespace** **Service**

In your **config.php** or **loader.php** do something like

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
        "Service" => $config->application->servicesDir,
    )
);
```

Your config should have the **servicesDir** set to something like **app/services**

Then if that all loads succsefully you can call your method "ProfileImage" like so

```
$app->getDI()->get('Service\Commonfunctions')
```

I hope this helps